# Is 'valid' a reserved name in DataMapper?

Tags: ruby, validation, sinatra, datamapper

I have the following model in datamapper:

```
class Student
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,          Serial
  # <snip>
  property :permissions, String, :accessor => :protected, :required => true, :default => 'standard'
  property :valid,       Boolean, :default => false, :required => true
  # <snip>
end
```

After requiring 'dm-validations' (version 1.1.0), and starting my Sinatra app, I recieve the following message:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-validations-1.1.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:81:in `valid?': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-validations-1.1.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:81:in `save_self'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:1007:in `_save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:1223:in `run_once'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:1006:in `_save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:406:in `save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-validations-1.1.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:69:in `save'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-validations-1.1.0/lib/dm-validations/support/context.rb:30:in `validation_context'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/dm-validations-1.1.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:69:in `save'
<snip>
```

Is the 'valid' name I'm using for my model a reserved word? If it is, where can I find these words. I'm to the point of going on to trying to name it something like: 'student_valid' but now i'm just really curious about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#valid? is a method that dm-validations adds. You cannot use "valid" as a property name because it automatically defines "valid?" method for a boolean property type which overrides dm-validations' valid?. Hence the error.

That's a tricky situation, I guess we need to improve the way we validate property names. Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this! Is there a way, other than calling `instance.methods` (As pointed out by @michael-papile in the other answer) to find all of these methods, since calling `instance.methods` will give me everything i've defined unioned with things defined by other objects like DataMapper

Comment: All methods that are reserved by DM Property are listed in DataMapper::Property::INVALID_NAMES constant.

The problem you discovered is caused by the fact that Property only validates its name and in case of Boolean property it should also check "#{name}?" which will be defined too and may collide with already existing method.

Comment: Just FYI - DataMapper 1.1.1 will include an improved property name validation which will raise an exception if you try to use "valid" as the name.

Answer (score 2):

Well the way datamapper works, is that it uses `method_missing` at the end of the method call chain and finds your property.  If there is a method with this same name then that is called rather than your property.  Datamapper mixes in `Validatable` which has the method valid?  Most of the time you learn what is reserved (Like all `Object` methods etc.) But if you want a full list you can do:

```
  `myinstance.methods`
```

Anything that appears there will get called first.

Comment: The accepted answer provides the solution I was looking for, BUT, I was being silly when trying to figure it out and was calling `Student.methods`, not as you pointed out `instance.methods`, So thank you very much for this too!